# Deleting part of html code from iframe

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

I have an asp.net page where I put some iframe. I want to delete a part of html code from this iframe in code behind. How to do it? For searching and deleting html code on page, will be helpfull regex or HAP. But how to get inside of this iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iframe is on a different domain you can't access it via JS (assuming you're using javascript or similar to do it).

http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy